# What is this transformer-like component with only two leads

Tags: components

I found this while taking apart a PSU, the closest label was B1. It appears to be a transformer-like component with two leads, and the coils on the vertical part around the core seem to be connected opposite the leads. Googling the label got me nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I got some leads on the inscription, but they all seem to point to the frame of the unit which is apparently called U3216. For example [this](http://detail.china.alibaba.com/buyer/offerdetail/449189727.html)

Comment: Looks to me like it's just an inductor - kind of like a toroidal one with a closed loop for the induction core, just not in the shape of a toroid.

Comment: Dumping a 3000 x 2250 picture on us is ridiculous.  It should be resized to 800 max.  It wouldn't hurt to hold the camera still and focus more carefully either next time.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop: Welcome here for a possible solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-ph/101446#101446 No need even for reupload - just change the link. `m` infix yields an even smaller image.

Comment: @Sharp: I didn't know about that, but I also fixed the colors while I was at it.  Hopefully the while plastic looking thingy really is white.  It was very dark in the original.

Comment: It would also help if you put a ruler next to it for scale.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: The image is automatically resized to 600px wide.  Complain to the site's software engineers, not to the users.

Comment: @endolith: No, it's not automatically resized, and it shouldn't be.  Sometimes high resolution is needed, but not in this case, especially considering the focusing and camera shake.  The root cause is inappropriate resolution supplied by the user, so that's exactly who to complain to.  I understand digital cameras nowadays produce high res pictures, but there is no excuse for dumping the raw picture on us without properly resizing it and other post processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just an inductor, it's used in some large switched mode psus to do powerfactor correction.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was going to say too.